# OpenGL with FBO RTT, blending when it shouldn't

Tags: c++, opengl, blend, fbo, render-to-texture

This should be really simple, but it's consumed multi-hours of my time, and I have no clue what's going on.

I'm rendering a flat-colored full-screen quad to a texture, then reading back the result with glGetTexImage. It's GPGPU related, so I want the alpha value to behave as if it's any of the other three. I'm using an FBO, texture format `GL_RGBA32F_ARB`, NVidia card on a MacBook Pro with 10.5, if it matters.

I only get back the correct color if the alpha I specify is one; with any other value it appears to be blending with what's already in the framebuffer, even though I've explicitly disabled `GL_BLEND`. I also tried enabling blending and using `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO)` but the end result is the same. I can clear the framebuffer to zero before rendering, which fixes it, but I want to understand why that's necessary. As a second test, rendering two overlapping quads gives a blended result, when I just want the original 4-channel color back. Surely the solid color quad should be overwriting pixels in the framebuffer completely? I'm guessing I've misunderstood something fundamental. Thanks.

```
 const size_t res = 16;
 GLuint tex;
 glGenTextures(1, &tex);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
 glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
 glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
 glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_FALSE);
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F_ARB,
  res, res, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

 GLuint fbo;
 glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &fbo);
 glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fbo);
 glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT,
  GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
 glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);

 glViewport(0, 0, res, res);
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glOrtho(0, res, 0, res, -1, 1);

 glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

 //glEnable(GL_BLEND);
 //glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
 glDisable(GL_BLEND);
 glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

 glColor4f(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5);

 for (int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glVertex2i(0,0);
  glVertex2i(res, 0);
  glVertex2i(res, res);
  glVertex2i(0, res);
  glEnd();
 }

 glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);

 std::vector<float> tmp(res*res*4);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
 glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,
  GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, &tmp.front());
 const float * const x = &tmp.front();
 cerr << x[0] << " " << x[1] << " " << x[2] << " " << x[3] << endl;
 // prints 0.3 0.45 0.6 0.75

 glDeleteTextures(1, &tex);
 glDeleteFramebuffersEXT(1, &fbo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really a good answer, however, some things to note:

- What you're observing does not really look like blending. For one, your back-buffer is initially rgba=0, so alpha-blending against it would give 0, not 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 like you may observe.
- my inclination was that you somehow set the same texture buffer as texture *and* framebuffer attachement. This is undefined in the spec [(section 4.4.3)](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/ogl-sample/registry/EXT/framebuffer_object.txt). In the code snippet you provide, you do a `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)` though, which should make sure it is not the case... I'll let it here in case you've missed it.